# Authorization set up for Rails app with VK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have application which works on Rails. I am using devise and omniauth-vkontakte.
My app can authorize user with vk.com but after user has passed authorization my navigation menu disappears. 
Navigation menu code is in `views/layouts/application.html.erb:`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="authentication">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <span>Hello, <%= current_user.email %></span>
          <%= button_to 'Exit', destroy_user_session_path, {:method => :delete} %>

      <% else %>
          <%= button_to 'sign up', new_user_registration_path,
                        {class: 'btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-info', id: 'sign-up-link', :method => :get} %>
          <%= button_to 'sign in', new_user_session_path, {class: 'btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-info', id: 'sign-in-btn'} %>

      <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

And I have one more trouble. How can I do that when user has passed authorization via vkontakte there will be a exit button that redirects to the main page? 
Now it works like this: user passes auth with vkontankte and I have this message:

```
Users::OmniauthCallbacks#vkontakte
Find me in app/views/users/omniauth_callbacks/vkontakte.html.haml
```

Code in app/views/users/omniauth_callbacks/vkontakte.haml.html:

```
%h1 Users::OmniauthCallbacks#vkontakte
%p Find me in app/views/users/omniauth_callbacks/vkontakte.html.haml
```

Code in app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def vkontakte
  end

end
```

Comment: What exactly menu disappears? Can you paste code of this menu?

Comment: @denys281 dissapers <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">...</nav>
Do you need CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After authorization it redirects you to **def vkontakte end** method and you see it view.

So you can add some modification to this controller, something like `redirect_to root_path`. I don't now how you build your system but here example how you could implement it: [link](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142128/) (on Russian, but you can look at code)